# What security restrictions are placed on Powershell scripts run during a NuGet package install/init?

Tags: powershell, nuget

When you install a package from NuGet, it can run some Powershell scripts to set things up (such as exporting commands to be used in the Package Manager console).

I'm trying (and failing) to find details of what these scripts can/can't do. Specifically - should we be worried about malicious code in these? Can they read the filesystem, send web requests, etc.?

Comment: Base on the docs I'd say they are not restricted. You are probaly going to need filesystem or web access anyway to (un)install a package, so restricting that probably does not make too much sense.

Comment: Installing/uninstalling a package that copies binaries into a folder is a world apart from a script being able to read/write any file on your file system and send it over the web :)

Comment: I also suspect no restrictions (and the presence of a "Report Abuse" link also suggests this), but if that's the case, I think it should be made a little clearer the first time you install a new package that it could contain malicious code :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When NuGet sets up the PowerShell host, it checks to see what the current ExecutionPolicy is. If it is not Unrestricted, RemoteSigned, or Bypass, it forces the ExcecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned for the current process (devenv.exe).

PowerShell does not see the embedded scripts init.ps1, install.ps1, etc. as being downloaded from the Internet, so there is nothing preventing a malicious script from doing anything on your machine that your account has permissions to do.

At this point, all NuGet package creators are pretty much on the "honor" system. I believe Ruby Gems have a similar situtation.

NuGet does have the ability to use private package sources, so if security is critical, I suggest you download and vet all packages, and only allow installing packages from these trusted sources.

Comment: It wasn't me I was worried about, just the average programmer. I guess in reality, the code in the binaries could do pretty much anything too, so we need to trust the author. I think maybe it should be made clearer in the NuGet dialogs how destructive/malicious the packages *could* be.

Answer (score 0):

I'll defer to someone from the NuGet team, but I'm almost certain they run under the current execution policy.

Here's a clip from my own nuget console:

```
PM> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

If I open PowerShell as an admin and change the execution policy, nuget reports the change:

```
PM> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Restricted
```

In sum, whatever execution policy you've got on your default host also applies to the nuget console.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm more confused. I thought the default policy was that all scripts had to be signed, but NuGet is running scripts downloaded from the web that are presumably unsigned?

Comment: The default policy is to not run scripts at all.  But it is very easy to change that policy.  It is not meant as a real security protection, more of a child safety lock.  :)

Comment: What I meant was, NuGet seems to run scripts "from the internet" that are not signed, regardless of the Execution Policy setting?

Answer (score -2):

When you download a script from the internet, unless it is installed with a setup program where you have given it escalated permissions to install, the scripts are marked as blocked.  You have to authorize (unblock) them by right clicking on the scripts and choosing the button Unblock.

Comment: I'm talking about scripts executed as part of a NuGet package install, which do not get flagged as coming from the web, and execute anyway.